# Split or merge actions by date

Tags: python, merge, split, sequence

I like to create a sequence database, based on different activities (ACT) on same or different dates. As you can see, some rows may contain NaN values. I need the final data to train a machine learning model on sequences of activities.

```
ID  ACT1        ACT2        ACT3        ACT4        ACT5    
0   2015-08-11  2015-08-16  2015-08-16  2015-09-22  2015-08-19
1   2014-07-16  2014-07-16  2014-09-16  NaT         2014-09-12
2   2016-07-16  NaT         2017-09-16  2017-09-16  2017-12-16
```

The expected output, which will split or merge based on the date values, would look like following table:

```
ID Sequence1  Sequence2  Sequence3  Sequence4  
0  ACT1       ACT2,ACT3  ACT5       ACT4
1  ACT1,ACT2  ACT5       ACT3
2  ACT1       ACT3,ACT4  ACT5
```

Following script will output a string with the whole sequence only:

```
df['Sequence'] = df.loc[:, cols].apply(lambda dr: ','.join(df.loc[:, cols].columns[dr.dropna().argsort()]), axis=1)

Sequence
ACT1,ACT2,ACT3,ACT5,ACT4
ACT1,ACT2,ACT5,ACT3
ACT1,ACT3,ACT4,ACT5
```

Comment: What values are in `cols`?

Comment: Dates YYYY-MM-DD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was challenging, but I believe this will work for you.

```
from collections import defaultdict
import pandas as pd

data = {
      'ACT1': [pd.Timestamp(year=2015, month=8, day=11),
               pd.Timestamp(year=2014, month=7, day=16),
               pd.Timestamp(year=2016, month=7, day=16)],
      'ACT2': [pd.Timestamp(year=2015, month=8, day=16),
               pd.Timestamp(year=2014, month=7, day=16),
               np.nan],
      'ACT3': [pd.Timestamp(year=2015, month=8, day=16),
               pd.Timestamp(year=2014, month=9, day=16),
               pd.Timestamp(year=2017, month=9, day=16)],
      'ACT4': [pd.Timestamp(year=2015, month=9, day=22),
               np.nan, 
               pd.Timestamp(year=2017, month=9, day=16)],
      'ACT5': [pd.Timestamp(year=2015, month=8, day=19),
               pd.Timestamp(year=2014, month=9, day=12),
               pd.Timestamp(year=2017, month=12, day=16)]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Unstack so we can create groups
unstacked = df.unstack().reset_index()

# This will keep track of our sequence data
sequences = defaultdict(list)

# Here we get our groups, e.g., 'ACT1,ACT2', etc.;
# We group by date first, then by original index (0,1,2)
for i, g in unstacked.groupby([0, 'level_1']):
    sequences[i[1]].append(','.join(g.level_0))

# How many sequences (columns) we're going to need
n_seq = len(max(sequences.values(), key=len))

# Any NaTs will always shift your data to the left,
# so to speak, so we need to right pad the rows 
for k in sequences:
    while len(sequences[k]) < n_seq:
        sequences[k].append('')

# Create column labels and make new dataframe
columns = ['Sequence{}'.format(i) for i in range(1, n_seq + 1)]
print pd.DataFrame(list(sequences.values()), columns=columns)

   Sequence1  Sequence2 Sequence3 Sequence4
0       ACT1  ACT2,ACT3      ACT5      ACT4
1  ACT1,ACT2       ACT5      ACT3          
2       ACT1  ACT3,ACT4      ACT5
```

Comment: Thank you, that perfectly worked! Only one question: What would need to change in the script, if we would not group on same dates, but make it sequential for each item by the default column order? So that we would have Sequence1 -ACT1, Sequence2 - ACT2 instead of Sequence1 ACT1,ACT2?

Comment: sorry to ask you again.

Comment: I don't quite follow. Can you give me a full example for what Sequence1 and 2 would look like?

Comment: Hope it formats correctly here: `   Sequence1  Sequence2 Sequence3 Sequence4 Sequence5
0       ACT1      ACT2          ACT3          ACT5           ACT4
1       ACT1      ACT2          ACT5          ACT3          
2       ACT1      ACT3          ACT4          ACT5` Essentially, only one action per column. If some occur on the same date, they will be split. Where it was Sequence1 (ACT1,ACT2) it should be Sequence1 (ACT1), Sequence2 (ACT2).

Comment: Ah, I see. So, where you loop over the groups, you need to get rid of the string join. The modified line is this:  sequences[i[1]].extend(g.level_0.values)

Comment: I just found that the last column is always empty. How can we avoid that it attaches `' '` also to the longest sequence? I feel the answer must be in `for k in sequences:`

Comment: Do you mean 1) the last column is totally empty, i.e., contains only `' '` and should be removed? Or do you mean 2) you would like to get rid of any `' '` in the last column?

Comment: 1) The last column is completely empty. The max(len) of items is 15 but it has 16 columns.

Comment: This shouldn't be happening. I'm going to suggest we continue this in Chat for debugging. https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173816/split-or-merge-actions-by-date