# Converting column names to numbers?

Tags: python, pandas, encoding, label, encode

I have following data structure in a pd DataFrame:

```
    ID  ACT1 ACT2 ACT3 ACT4 ACT5
1   0   0    1    1    1    1
2   1   1    0    0    0    0
3   2   1    1    0    1    0
```

ACT is the short term for an activity here, where the original data has way longer descriptions than ACTx.

Question: Would it be possible to convert the column names (except for `ID`) into numbers and print a corresponding list so that I can later see which number represent which string? See my last post to understand where it comes from ([Split or merge actions by date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50932977/split-or-merge-actions-by-date))

```
    ID  0    1    2    3    4
1   0   0    1    1    1    1
2   1   1    0    0    0    0
3   2   1    1    0    1    0
```

Why? I want to create a sequence database and in order to save some memory for later computations, I like to work with encoded labels. Ideally, I can then call a table, listing each corresponding coded label and true label.

```
Coded Label
0     ACT1
1     ACT2
2     ACT3
3     ACT4
4     ACT5
...
```

Any good solution in pandas or scikit learn is welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do so:

Create a df with encoded labels:

```
l = range(0,len(df.columns)-1)
a = list(df[df.columns.difference(['ID'])])
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Label': a, 'Coded':l})

   Coded Label
0      0  ACT1
1      1  ACT2
2      2  ACT3
3      3  ACT4
4      4  ACT5
```

And then rename the columns:

```
df = df.rename(columns=dict(zip(df1["Label"], df1["Coded"])))

   ID  0  1  2  3  4
1   0  0  1  1  1  1
2   1  1  0  0  0  0
3   2  1  1  0  1  0
```

### Edit

To keep the order of the columns, you can do so:

```
a = list(df)
a.remove('ID')
l = range(0,len(df.columns)-1)
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Label': a, 'Coded':l})
```

Comment: Seems it applies the alphabetical order when I output df1. Can I prevent that, i.e. keep the order of columns?

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate!

Answer (score 1):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':['0','1','2'],'ACT1':['0','1','1'],'ACT2':['1','0','1'],'ACT3':['1','0','0'],'ACT4':['1','0','1'],'ACT5':['1','0','0']})
col = {x:y for x,y in zip(df.columns.difference(['ID']),range(0,len(df.columns)-1))}
label_coded = pd.DataFrame(list(col.items()), columns=['Label', 'Coded'])
df = df.rename(columns=col)
```

**INPUT:**

```
    ACT1    ACT2    ACT3    ACT4    ACT5    ID
 0     0       1       1       1       1     0
 1     1       0       0       0       0     1
 2     1       1       0       1       0     2
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
    0   1   2   3   4   ID
0   0   1   1   1   1   0
1   1   0   0   0   0   1
2   1   1   0   1   0   2
```

**label_coded:**

```
Coded Label
0     ACT1
1     ACT2
2     ACT3
3     ACT4
4     ACT5
```